# magento2 Enforce character limits across multiple custom product fields

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, custom-options

I'm trying to enforce character limits, across multiple custom product fields.

So a product has custom fields name First Name and Last Name, and that combined they must be less than 23 characters.

How can this be done?

Comment: you share the code of custom fields? is is in ui_component?